# Storing functions call and list of parameters to invoke later

Tags: c++, locking

I have this code facing performance issues due to locks. See the sketch below (can't post actual code which is too big anyway):

```
XYZ::process()
{
  ...
  lock();
  processSharedData(id );
  unlock();
  ...
}

XYZ::processSharedData(obj id)
{
  obj a = accessDataAttr1(id);
  //do some integrity checks

  //evaluate some conditions and then
  func1(attr1, attr2, attr3, ...);

  obj b = accessDataAttr2(id);
  //do some integrity checks

  //evaluate some conditions and then
  func2(attr1, attr2, attr3, ...);

  obj c = accessDataAttr3(id);
  //do some integrity checks

  //evaluate some conditions and then
  func3(attr1, attr2, attr3, ...);

  //do some clean up
  return;
}
```

Now I would like to move out the func1, func2 and func3 from the lock/unlock scope. Please suggest efficient way to do so. Is there a way to store function call with it's parameters to invoke it later?

How about storing all the parameters in a member struct and the function pointers in a std::list?

EDIT:

Sorry for not mentioning this before that c++11 is not yet available to me. Any solution without std:function and std:bind would be great for now.

Comment: Look up [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: Can't use them. See my comments for other posts.

Answer (score 5):

sure you can do this:

```
typedef std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> f_list;

XYZ::process() {
  //our function list
  f_list fl;
  lock();
  fl=processSharedData(id );
  unlock();
  //invoke functions
  for(auto& f : fl) f();
}

f_list XYZ::processSharedData(obj id) {
  f_list fl;
  obj a = accessDataAttr1(id);
  //do some integrity checks

  fl.push_back(
       std::bind(&func1, attr1, attr2, attr3)
  );

  obj b = accessDataAttr2(id);
  //do some integrity checks

  //evaluate some conditions and then
  fl.push_back(
       std::bind(&func2, attr1, attr2, attr3)
  );
  //and so on
  return fl;
}
```

### reference

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Thanks. Looks great but any solution without std:function and std::bind?

Comment: also don't forget bind and function are both aviable from boost

Comment: Part of big product development so I can't decide on using new standards/versions. No one is using boost either in my company.

Comment: @LovelyVirus I realise that what you have is a common issue, but it's silly non the less. Boost is a high quality library with a permissive (commericail friendly) free license. I can't really help you any more than this. I suggest that you tell your superiors that such limitations on C++11 and/or boost is making your job unecessarily difficult and/or producing an inferior product.

Comment: I agree with you. Why not use the latest tech available? Possibly for the new release of our product they might use it but I have to fix the problem in older release so sadly have to live with what is available. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 4):

To build upon the answer from 111111, if the functions you want to call are member function in the `XYZ` class, you have to pass the instance as the first argument:

```
fl.push_back(
    std::bind(&func1, this, attr1, attr2, attr3)
);
```

Later when you call the functions you can use another new feature in C++11: The [range-based for loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Range-based_for-loop):

```
for (auto f : fl)
    f();
```

Comment: as mentioned in response to other posts, c++11 is not yet available to me.